# Why doesn't using nonlocal scope variable as default value for parameter work?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, optional-arguments

Code would explain this much better :)

```
def a():
    x=0
    def b(z=x):
        print("X: %d, Z: %d" % (x,z,))
    x=5
    b()
```

Result:

```
X: 5, Z: 0
```

What's going on here?

(Ok, now I've figured it out)

Comment: You say you figured it out...please do post your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the answer from the Python docs is:

> **Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is executed.** This means that the expression is evaluated once, when the function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used for each call.

Fair enough.

Comment: This is the same underlying reason for the behaviour of mutable default arguments that often trips people up, and also the same underlying reason that default parameters can be used in "factory-produced" lambdas to "bind" values at creation.